# How can I reloop through an if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

This is my code. So if the answer isn't 1 or 2. The script should re-ask the question. But for some reason this isn't working.

```
question = input("Choose option 1 or 2: ")

if question == '1':
   pass
elif question == '2':
   pass
else:
   while question != '1' or question != '2':
      print("Error. You didn't select a valid option")
      question = input("Choose option 1 or 2: ")
```

How is this wrong? Why isn't it exiting out of the while loop if I get an incorrect answer the first time and getting a correct answer the second time?

Comment: Because if the answer is 1 then it isn't 2. If the answer is 2, it isn't 1.

Comment: It should be `question != '1' and question != '2'`

Comment: That didn't work. If I choose 1 as the answer it passes but if I choose 2 it loops back again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce your code to this:

```
question = input("Choose option 1 or 2: ")

while question not in ['1', '2']:
    print("Error. You didn't select a valid option")
    question = input("Choose option 1 or 2: ")
```

In case you are using Python 3.8+, you can reduce it even further:

```
while question := input("Choose option 1 or 2: ") not in ['1', '2']:
    print("Error. You didn't select a valid option")
```

After either `'1'` or `'2'` was chosen, you can handle the cases accordingly:

```
if question == '1' do_stuff() else do_other_stuff()

def do_stuff():
    pass


def do_other_stuff():
    pass
```

Comment: this will also take '12' as an answer

Comment: Ah true! Forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the if statement in the while loop!

```
question = input("Choose option 1 or 2: ")

while (question != '1' or question != '2'):
    print("Error. You didn't select a valid option")
    question = input("Choose option 1 or 2: ")
    if question == '1' or question == '2':
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

here your code is looping but there is not way to go back to the first if else statments...
so using `break` in `while True:` is a better approach :

```
while True:
    question = input("Choose option 1 or 2: ")
    if question in ['1','2']:
        break
    print('Error. You didn"t select a valid option')
print('done!')
```

console:

```
Choose option 1 or 2: >? 3
Error. You didn"t select a valid option
Choose option 1 or 2: >? 2
done!
```

Comment: I think you should remove the last line inside the loop. It’s a repeat of the first.

Comment: Yes, I thought so.

Comment: Yes, I do it all the time!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while True:
    question = int(input("Choose option 1 or 2: "))
    if question == 1:  #Check if question is equal to 1
        # Do something
        break
    elif question == 2: #Check if question is equal to 2
        #do something
        break
    else:
        print("Number must be 1 or 2.") # " Raise error "
        continue # Continue the loop
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT**

```
>>> Choose option 1 or 2: 3
>>> Number must be 1 or 2.
>>> Choose option 1 or 2:
```

Comment: The ‘continue’ is redundant in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

`````
while (question!='1' and question!='2'):
    if question == '1':
        print ('You selected 1')
    elif question == '2':
        print('You selected 2')
    else:
        print('Error. You didn"t select a valid option')
        question = input("Choose option 1 or 2: ")````
`````

Comment: `AND` most be `and` for python to recognize it as a keyword